# Looking for references for real-world scenarios of data-poisoning attack on labels while doing supervised learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, adversary

Consider the following mathematical model of training a neural net : Suppose $f_{w} : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a neural net whose weights are $w$. Suppose during the training the adversary is sampling $x \sim {\cal D}$ from some distribution ${\cal D}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and sending in training data of the form $(x, \theta(x) + f_{w^*}(x))$ i.e the adversary is corrupting the true labels generated by $f_{w^*}$ (for some fixed $w^*$) by adding a real number to it.

Now suppose we want to have an algorithm which will use such corrupted training data as above and try to get as close to $w*$ as possible i.e  despite getting data corrupted the above way the algorithm is trying to minimize (over $w$) the "original risk" $\mathbb{E}_{x \sim {\cal D}} \left [ \frac{1}{2} \left ( f_w (x) - f_{w*}(x) \right )^2 \right ]$ as best as possible.

- Is there a real life deep-learning application which comes close to the above framework or can motivate the above algorithmic aim?

Comment: Assuming $\theta$ can depend on $x$, this problem is impossible to solve. For example, an adversary can choose $\theta(x) = -f_{w^*}(x)$ and thus the data point will be $(x,0)$ for every $x$

Comment: You need some sort of constraints on $\theta$ that will make sure this kind of behavior is not allowed, otherwise you wont be able to do anything. Such a constraint can be done in the extreme case by only allowing **one** $\theta$ for every $x$. You can have other constraints, like $\theta$ must be a normal distribution, where the adversary is allowed to choose the parameters - but it will be harder to analyze.

Comment: Sure! I am in the algorithmic proof going to make assumptions on $\theta$. Mostly I am going to assume a constant bound on $\theta$ and all guarantees will be in terms of this bound. I do not want to assume any fixed distribution on $\theta$ since that makes it a noise and not an attack. With noise model this becomes a more standard question with known standard solutions. 

What I am looking for are references for real world usecases which can motivate such a mathematical model.

Comment: Is boundness the only assumption you make? it seems not strong enough for some problems, however in such problems your loss will still be small - the problems that are entirely contained in the bounds you have will have the same attack. Since they are bounded, a constant function that returns any value within the bounds will not be too far away from the actual function you are learning. This however probably does not sound like something you would want, even though it can work.

Comment: Assuming the bound is small enough (and significantly smaller than the actual ranges the function can get), I think you should look at the LWE (Learning With Errors) problem, since (if I remember correctly) it gives a similar model to what you are describing.

Comment: What research have you done?  There are probably hundreds of papers on dealing with label noise and dealing with data poisoning, which you should be able to find with standard techniques (Google Scholar, related work sections, searching for papers that cite another relevant paper).  Have you studied that literature?  Are you satisfied with the applications described there?  If not, why not, and what are your requirements?  I suggest you do some research, then use that to improve your question.

Comment: I am probably more familiar with neural net theory literature than most people! To the best of my understanding, this model I have described has not been been analyzed anywhere and I know that this is analytically tractable if $\theta(x)$ is bounded.

Comment: Its key point here to understand that this is NOT label noise. If the $\theta(x)$ is sampled from a "reasonable" fixed distribution then the question becomes quite standard. The interesting case is when $\theta(x)$ is an adversarial attack - like a fixed function mapping $x$ to $\mathbb{R}$. 

My wonder is if this model is naturally seen in real world. Are there known learning situations which are close to this?

Comment: @nirshahar Boundedness on $\theta(x)$ is enough to get a guarantee on how low a value of the "original" risk that I can get via an algorithm. How low I can get worsens with the bound on $\theta$.